# EXCEL FORMULA/MACRO : Return matching data in the same column

Tags: vba, excel

Here's the scenario: I have two columns with "thread codes" and "Time". I need to loop through the thread code (Column A in the sample data) to find the next match and return the Time for it in the 3rd column. If a thread code is already found, the formula should skip it but continue looping through the remaining values in the column.

Here's the sample data:

```
    Command & Thread               Time         End Time (Expected Result)
clearVideoCache0x16e6ef000    1461178638535256  1461178638575052
clearVideoCache0x16e6ef000    1461178638575052  Already Used
clearVideoCache0x16e0a3000    1461178639330011  1461178639366057
clearVideoCache0x16e0a3000    1461178639366057  Already Used
session/start0x16e6ef000      1461178648045939  1461178648451464
session/start0x16e6ef000      1461178648451464  Already Used
user0x16e6ef000               1461178648505997  1461178648925134
user0x16e6ef000               1461178648925134  Already Used
system/properties0x16e6ef000  1461178648992088  1461178649223747
system/properties0x16e6ef000  1461178649223747  Already Used
activation/device0x16e6ef000  1461178649319258  1461178649949353
activation/device0x16e6ef000  1461178649949353  Already Used
subscription/0x16e6ef000      1461178650000950  1461178650391812
recordings0x16eb4f000         1461178650019638  1461178651156481
subscription/0x16e6ef000      1461178650391812  Already Used
subscription/0x16e6ef000      1461178650443640  1461178650877673
subscription/0x16e6ef000      1461178650877673  Already Used
user/subscriptions0x16e6ef000 1461178650926804  1461178651900302
recordings0x16eb4f000         1461178651156481  Already Used
user/subscriptions0x16e6ef000 1461178651900302  Already Used
```

Here's my code so far:

```
"=IFERROR(INDEX($E$1:INDEX(E:E,MATCH(""ZZZ"",D:D)),AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW($D$1:INDEX(D:D,MATCH(""ZZZ"",D:D)))/($D$1:INDEX(D:D,MATCH(""ZZZ"",D:D))=D2),COUNTIF($D$1:$D2,D2))), ""NO MATCH"")"
```

However, this returns the same value I'm using to lookup, not the next matching value in the column. If no match is found, "NO MATCH" message should be displayed in the cell. Also, I need to apply a Macro for that formula. Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Comment: You should provide an example of expected result.  Also are you looking for a macro (vba) solution?  You have provided a function but no coding towards a macro.

Comment: I made an edit and added a column to provide the expected result. I do need a macro for it too, but I could only get as far as a formula for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try with below code.

```
Sub test()
    Dim matchcount, lastrow, i, j As Long
    Dim searchtext As String
    Dim rng1 As Range
    lastrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        searchtext = Range("A" & i).Value
        For j = i + 1 To lastrow
            If searchtext = Range("A" & j).Value Then
                matchcount = matchcount + 1
                If matchcount = 1 Then
                    Range("C" & i).Value = Range("B" & j).Value
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next j
        Set rng1 = Range("A2:A" & i - 1).Find(searchtext)
        If ((Not rng1 Is Nothing) And (matchcount = 0)) Then
            Range("C" & i).Value = "Already used"
        ElseIf (rng1 Is Nothing) And (matchcount = 0) Then
            Range("C" & i).Value = "No Match"
        End If
        If matchcount <> 0 Then
            matchcount = 0
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Proof of Work**

[image]

please see the red mark text which is wrong in your expected result.

**EDIT 2**

As per your comment table it will be like below. please confirm?

[image]

Comment: this works, but some of the matches are still not returning the right result. As I said, if a match is already found once, it should be ignored with "Already used" command, but this is not happening. See below for some of the entries in the table. 
`lookup0x16e663000 1461178707903507 1461178707903631`
`lookup0x16e663000 1461178707903631 1461178707903707`
`lookup0x16e663000 1461178707903707 1461178707903797`
`lookup0x16e663000 1461178707903797 1461178707903878`
`lookup0x16e663000 1461178707903878 1461178707903967`
`lookup0x16e663000 1461178707903967 1461178707904070`

Comment: see the table here...I'm unable to properly format the table in the comment [Table](http://imgur.com/6Lc2BMw)